# dynamic VML element creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, vml

I am creating the VML element dynamically.Please refer below code.

```
<html> 
<head>  
<!-- VML requires VML namespace and behavior. --> 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Flag to stop rectangle from spinning. 
    var spin;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.namespaces.add('v', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml', "#default#VML");
        // Create element in memory. 
        var r = document.createElement("v:rect");
        // Define width, height, color, and unique ID.
        $(r).css("width", "100");
        $(r).css("height", "100");
        $(r).attr("fillcolor", "blue");
        $(r).attr("strokecolor", "red");
        $(r).attr("strokeweight", "5");
        $(r).css('left', '100');
        $(r).css('top', '100');
        $(r).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(r).css('opacity', '0.2');
        r.id = "myRect";
        // Attach rectangle to the document at the  the specified Div. 
        anchorDiv.appendChild(r);

    });

</script>  
</head>  
<body>  

<div id="anchorDiv"></div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Which displays the output in  **browser mode -> IE 7 and document mode -> IE 5** .Please refer below image.

[image]

but after am changing the **document mode -> IE 7** nothing displayed.(i.e. blank screen). then  **i clicked edit button two times in developer tools of IE browser**.  Please refer below image

[image]

it displays the rectangle. i don't know  what is the reason for this ? and some times even in IE 5 document mode itself rectangle not showing then i followed same procedure ( **clicked edit button two times in developer tools of IE browser**),it will displays the rectangle. can some explain what's going wrong on this ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: then how can i display the VML element in IE7 and IE8  browser with different document modes.

Comment: no.it is possible. see highcharts.com they support all kind of browsers. for IE7 and IE8  they use VML only. am asking about IE 7  with IE7 mode and IE8 mode not standard mode. for standard mode i will render SVG. for IE8,IE7 modes i need to render VML

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding multiple VML elements via JavaScript in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404955/adding-multiple-vml-elements-via-javascript-in-ie8)